# Pandas: How to write a faster loop which checks one column and then changes the signs of another column, depending on the value of the first column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have about 10 million lines of data in my dataframe. Below is an example of how it looks like for 2 rows.

| index | Amount | debit/credit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1000 | 1 |
| 1 | 2000 | 2 |

i want to write a function that checks if the value in the "debit/credit" column is a 1 for debit or a 2 for credit. And replaces the figure in the "Amount" column with a negative number if it is a 2. So for example, the table will change to this:

| index | Amount | debit/credit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1000 | 1 |
| 1 | -2000 | 2 |

Here is the function i wrote but its really slow for 9million lines. Could anyone advise me how do  i refactor this code? or is there a more efficient way to perform this task? (using python or sql. preferrably python.)

```
def change_credits_to_negative(df):
    for num in range(len(df)):
        if df['debit/credit'].loc[num] == 2: # 1 is for debit & 2 is for credit
            df['Amount'].loc[num] = -df['Amount'].loc[num]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more a system performance (execution time) analysis rather than an answer, although it suggests slight improvement on the processing time of the 2 solutions:

Using `- df['Amount']` is faster than `df['Amount'] * -1` since `+/-` operations are faster than `* /` operations.

Hence, suggest to use:

```
df.loc[df['debit/credit'].eq(2), 'Amount'] = - df['Amount']
```

instead of: `df.loc[df['debit/credit'].eq(2), 'Amount'] *= -1`

For the `np.where()` solution, suggest to use:

```
df['Amount'] = np.where(df['debit/credit'].eq(2), - df['Amount'], df['Amount'])
```

instead of `df['Amount'] = np.where(df['debit/credit'].eq(2), df['Amount']*-1, df['Amount'])`

### Benchmarking results:

1. `df.loc` solution:

```
%%timeit
df.loc[df['debit/credit'].eq(2), 'Amount'] *= -1

728 µs ± 14.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
df.loc[df['debit/credit'].eq(2), 'Amount'] *= - df.loc[df['debit/credit'].eq(2), 'Amount']

1.08 ms ± 10.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
df.loc[df['debit/credit'].eq(2), 'Amount'] = - df['Amount']

689 µs ± 22.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

The 2nd one with `df.loc` at both sides are the slowest probably because the `.loc` processing also takes time.  The 3rd one is fastest.

2. `np.where` solution:

```
%%timeit
df['Amount'] = np.where(df['debit/credit'].eq(2), df['Amount']*-1, df['Amount'])

539 µs ± 14.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
df['Amount'] = np.where(df['debit/credit'].eq(2), - df['Amount'], df['Amount'])

498 µs ± 2.62 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**`- df['Amount']` outperforms `df['Amount'] * -1` in both solutions.**

Answer (score 6):

You could do it with `.loc`, but without a loop:

```
df.loc[df['debit/credit'].eq(2), 'Amount'] *= -1
```

Output:

```
    Amount  debit/credit
0     1000             1
1    -2000             2
```

**OR**

via `np.where()`:

```
import numpy as np

df['Amount'] = np.where(df['debit/credit'].eq(2), df['Amount']*-1, df['Amount'])
```

**PERFORMANCE TESTS:**

Let's create a sample dataframe with 2 columns and 10 million rows:

```
import time

df = pd.DataFrame({'Amount': np.random.randint(1000, 10000, size=10000000),
                   'debit/credit': np.random.randint(1, size=10000000) + 1})
```

*1) LOOP:*

```
start = time.perf_counter()

change_credits_to_negative(df)

stop = time.perf_counter()
print(stop - start)

97.34215749999998
```

*2) LOC:*

```
start = time.perf_counter()

df.loc[df['debit/credit'].eq(2), 'Amount'] *= -1

stop = time.perf_counter()
print(stop - start)

0.03006110000001172
```

It gives us 97 sec. with the loop and 0.03 sec. without it.

Answer (score 1):

Other way around:

```
df.loc[df['debit/credit'].astype(str).str.contains('2'), 'Amount'] *= -1
print(df)
   Amount  debit/credit
0    1000             1
1   -2000             2
```